# Problems during running Principia

Tags: mingw, permission-denied

I am working on MSYS2 MinGW and when I tried to run a file by typing `./go`, error occured :

```
$ ./go
  CXXLD    principia.exe
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin/ld.exe: cannot find ../src/lua: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4131: principia.exe] Error 1
```

Before this procedure, I typed `./configure` and it worked correctly. I don't know how to fix this.
I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried with antivirus disabled?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it before but the result was same.